# Jesus asleep on the boat .. Was He really asleep

Tags: greek, hebrew, matthew, jesus, gospels

Matthew 8:24

> Suddenly a violent storm came up on the sea, so that the boat was engulfed by the waves; but Jesus was sleeping.

(See also parallel passages in Mark 4 & Luke 8)

Was Jesus really asleep? What is the spiritual significance? Is this a metaphor? A mentor of mine said that Jesus was actually in a trance is there any references in Greek or Hebrew that say this?

Comment: Hi Troy, welcome to the site! I added some formatting & references to your question. I can roll back the edits if you don't like them.

Comment: What support did your friend offer for his statement?

Comment: _the LORD'S throne is in heaven: his eyes behold, **his eyelids try**, the children of men._ Psalm 11:4.

Answer (score 4):

Let us examine the three parallel records of Jesus "sleeping" as recorded in the NT.

In **Matt 8:24 and Mark 4:38**, the verb used is καθεύδω (katheudó) which is used in the NT in three basic ways:

1. to fall asleep or be asleep, eg, Matt 8:24, 9:24, Mark 4:27, 38, 14:37, Luke 8:52, 22:46, etc.
2. to be physically dead, Luke 8:52, 1 Thess 5:10, Matt 9:24, Mark 5:39, etc
3. to be spiritually asleep, ie, insensitive to salvation, eg, Mark 13:36, Eph 5:14, 1 Thess 5:6, etc.

Thus, Matthew and Mark record Jesus as actually sound asleep - so tired that the noise of the storm did not wake Him. The disciples woke Him up.

In **Luke 8:23** the Greek uses a different word for sleep, namely, ἀφυπνόω (aphupnoo), a hapex legomenon meaning to "fall asleep".  Thus, Luke also records Jesus sleeping.

**Awaken**

The above is confirmed by the different words used by the writers to describe Jesus being awoken from sleep:

- Matt 8:25, Mark 4:38 - ἐγείρω (egeiró) means to awaken, rise up, eg, Matt 1;24, 2:13, etc
- Luke 8:24 - διεγείρω (diegeiró) means to wake out of sleep, arouse, stir up.

If the NT writers had wanted to say that Jesus was in a trance (ie, not asleep) they had other words, eg, ἔκστασις (ekstasis) such as is used of Peter's trance in Acts 10:10, 11:5; and Paul's trance in Acts 22:17.

Thus, there is no doubt that Jesus was sleeping soundly after an exhausting day of preaching and ministry.

Comment: A good and well-grounded answer. The intrigue is that He is sleeping but at the same time holding the entire universe into existence, for Logos as Logos cannot sleep in His divine nature and even personality, thus He sleeps in human nature, but cannot sleep  in divine nature, so He sleeps and also does not sleep; just like He dies according to human nature but cannot  die in divine nature, which is necessarily immortal and changeless. And how is this so is a mystery.

Comment: @LevanGigineishvili - agreed - good point and great comment.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not toward that part of your question which asks if Jesus really slept or not because @Dottard has done a good job answering that, I believe. You also asked of what spiritual significance this is and toward that end I want to share with you a lengthy quote from a book I have read about the life of Christ. It points out two ways that this miracle is of spiritual significance to us.

> "When Jesus was awakened to meet the storm, He was in perfect peace. There was no trace of fear in word or look, for no fear was in His heart. But He rested not in the possession of almighty power. It was not as the "Master of earth and sea and sky" that He reposed in quiet. That power He had laid down, and He says, "I can of Mine own self do nothing." John 5:30. He trusted in the Father's might. It was in faith—faith in God's love and care—that Jesus rested, and the power of that word which stilled the storm was the power of God.
> As Jesus rested by faith in the Father's care, so we are to rest in the care of our Saviour. If the disciples had trusted in Him, they would have been kept in peace. Their fear in the time of danger revealed their unbelief. In their efforts to save themselves, they forgot Jesus; and it was only when, in despair of self-dependence, they turned to Him that He could give them help.
> How often the disciples' experience is ours! When the tempests of temptation gather, and the fierce lightnings flash, and the waves sweep over us, we battle with the storm alone, forgetting that there is One who can help us. We trust to our own strength till our hope is lost, and we are ready to perish. Then we remember Jesus, and if we call upon Him to save us, we shall not cry in vain. Though He sorrowfully reproves our unbelief and self-confidence, He never fails to give us the help we need. Whether on the land or on the sea, if we have the Saviour in our hearts, there is no need of fear. Living faith in the Redeemer will smooth the sea of life, and will deliver us from danger in the way that He knows to be best.
> There is another spiritual lesson in this miracle of the stilling of the tempest. Every man's experience testifies to the truth of the words of Scripture, "The wicked are like the troubled sea, when it cannot rest.... There is no peace, saith my God, to the wicked." Isaiah 57:20, 21. Sin has destroyed our peace. While self is unsubdued, we can find no rest. The masterful passions of the heart no human power can control. We are as helpless here as were the disciples to quiet the raging storm. But He who spoke peace to the billows of Galilee has spoken the word of peace for every soul. However fierce the tempest, those who turn to Jesus with the cry, "Lord, save us," will find deliverance. His grace, that reconciles the soul to God, quiets the strife of human passion, and in His love the heart is at rest. "He maketh the storm a calm, so that the waves thereof are still. Then are they glad because they be quiet;  so He bringeth them unto their desired haven." Psalm 107:29, 30. "Being justified by faith, we have peace with God through our Lord Jesus Christ." "The work of righteousness shall be peace; and the effect of righteousness quietness and assurance forever." Romans 5:1; Isaiah 32:17." The Desire of Ages p. 336

I hope this can help you. I can look for a link to the book if you are interested to read the rest of the chapter about just this one miracle.

Comment: Since the comments were deleted by Steve (the admin) evidently due to their multiplicity that went against the decorum of the site, I still decided to recapitulate my comment on Mrs. Ellen's passage, for it is an important point and I think she gets the point wrong, which can be perilous for a reader. To wit: Christ has never ever relinquished or "laid down" His power and authority over elements (wind, hail, tsunami etc.), but even in this passage He, in a sovereign authority, without prayers to Father, Himself calms down the storm, showing Himself as Lord of the Psalm 107:29.

Answer (score 0):

Why was Jesus sleeping? Maybe He wasn't, maybe He was waiting.

Perhaps this part of the verse should remind us to go to Jesus always. In good times and in troubles. Even when it seems that He isn't present we need to call on Him for help.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics.SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Answer (score -1):

Since sleeping is an indispensable and non-sinful activity, or rather, passivity, of human being, like eating or yawning, and the Lord has adopted entire human nature but sin, then we can say freely that He slept in a human way throughout His earthly life and in particular, here, he slept on a boat.

Another thing is that His sleeping was still a different sleeping, in that He as the eternal Person of Logos is always alert and cannot get out of consciousness, like we do while sleeping, for oftentimes we sleep without even dreams, like a log. Thus, He sleeps but at the same time listens to prayers of all humans who pray to God, for it is absolutely and ontologically impossible for Father to hear prayers without His Son co-hearing them. It is the same as when He gets hungry: yes, He humanly gets hungry, but simultaneously provides food to all creatures of the earth, or is subjected to gravity as a creature, for His is the created body and the created intelligent soul in it - both being aspects of His human nature - but as Creator He is the Author of the laws of gravity and is not at all subject to them but can change them at will both for Himself and humans, for Peter also walked on water at His encouragement.

Thus, He sleeps humanly and simultaneously is awake as God, for wakefulness of the Father, the Son and the H. Ghost is the same wakefulness and God as God does not and cannot sleep.